# Email Editor Similar to Campaign Monitor or Mailchimp's editor?

Tags: email, editor, wysiwyg, mailchimp

I looking for either an open source (or otherwise) php script/library/code that will provide me with a similar email composer that Mailchimp and Campaign Monitor have.

I've played around with lots of wysiwyg editors (eg: tinymce, ckeditor) but, they don't work very well for allowing users to compose emails.

Comment: You should state which specific features you're searching for and why the existing editors doesn't fit your needs (provided that you have customized them properly).

Comment: I'm also looking for a beautiful, rich JavaScript editor similar to Campaign Monitor or Mailchimp's. Currently using CKEditor but it's not that great for creating rich content.

Comment: This is not the place, but I do need to vent my frustration with the Mailchimp editor - you cannot disable the autosave option. I've emailed them but they refuse to change it. :-(

Answer (score 6):

**Mosaico Editor** is the first open source **email template builder** of this kind (AFAIK).

You can find a free to use deployment (working also as live demo) at http://mosaico.io and you can get sources at https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico

I choose blocks from a set defined by the "**master template**", then you fill you contents and change their styles in a **WYSIWYG** style. If you're on a large window you can also have live preview for the mobile version.

The master template defines what are the blocks, what you can edit and what you can style and it contains any html trick to make it compatible with most clients: this means you can change the editor behaviour a lot by simply writing a new master template.

[image]
It is 99% javascript (IE10+, and any other modern browser) and depends on server-side functions only to do "final inlining" and "image upload/resizing"

Answer (score 1):

[image: Grapejs]

Next generation tool for building templates without coding

[Grapejs official site](http://grapesjs.com/)

GrapesJS is an open-source, multi-purpose, Web Builder Framework which combines different tools and features with the goal to help you (or users of your application) to build HTML templates without any knowledge of coding. It's a perfect solution to replace the common WYSIWYG editors, which are good for content editing but inappropriate for creating HTML structures. You can see it in action with the official demos, but using its API you're able to build your own editors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of building one but as a designer it is a work in progress! I'd suggest looking at [PHP template engines](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/). They have a similar functionality. Most however will use php variables inside the html page instead of  tags.

Another oprion is to check out [Perch](https://grabaperch.com/) it is officially a CMS, but is really lightweight and might get the job done for you.

Hope that helps even though it is a year after you posted the question...

EDIT: Actually just stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125107/email-template-editor-similar-to-campaign-monitor) thread which links to the new CKEditor - looks pretty cool.

Comment: A point to be noted is that he needs it for emails. Most WYSIWYG text editors add <div> and <span> tags with inline style. For example if I add font colors in TinyMCE, it uses a <span> with inline style attribute. Most email programs simply rip off all styling in these tags. What they implement is old <font> tags. So how to configure these editors (CKeditor, tinymce etc.) to output <font> tags instead of <span> ?

Comment: @Zeeshan Campaign Monitor's editor really focuses on the text, typically you'd put the `<multiline>` tag inside your email templates `<font>` tags. Used the same way, you can limit the options on CK or Tiny editors, only allowing straight text input and controlling styling in the template code.

Comment: Sure I could limit the users to enter plain text only and handle the styling in backend, but the question basically was about an editor that allows users to handle the same. For example the way gmail does. I haven't looked at campaign monitor but mailchimp does allow users to type colored text directly in the editor. That is what I am currently looking for as well.

Comment: PS: He mentioned that the need is for a fully working, email-friendly WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: You can add colored text to Campaign Monitors editor as well. It uses spans which work in email. There is no email specific wysiwyg available to my knowledge, so you'll have to tweak the output string to convert it to email-friendly html. PHP works well for this, particularly because most of the wysiwyg solutions mentioned are php based anyway.