# Email template editor similar to Campaign Monitor

Tags: php, email, templates, editor

I need to do a similar email template editor as Campaign Monitor have (http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/). I tried a lot of wysiwyg editors, but it doesn't work as i want.

Do you know which technologies are used? I don't know how to do a panel which will edit the content on a right side.

If you have some tips, good resources, articles, I'll be really glad!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking into this myself, as our CMS is being rebuilt and needs better WYSIWYG editors. They use a heavily modified version of CKEditor http://www.ckeditor.com

CKEditor has a version 4 in beta which will support in-line editing (something we need) so I'll be watching this one closely. Demo's at http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/3466/samples/

Comment: Did you ever create a rich email editor with CKEditor?

Answer (score 0):

Their technology is proprietary. In the last few years every ESP created its own editor of this kind.

**Mosaico Editor** is the first open source **email template builder** in this class.

You can find a free to use deployment (working also as live demo) at http://mosaico.io and you can get sources at https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico

You can choose blocks from a set defined by the "**master template**", then you fill you contents and change their styles in a **WYSIWYG** style. If you're on a large window you can also have live preview for the mobile version.

The master template defines what are the blocks, what you can edit and what you can style and it contains any html trick to make it compatible with most clients: this means you can change the editor behaviour a lot by simply writing a new master template.

[image: email template builder screenshot]
It is 99% javascript (IE10+, and any other modern browser) and depends on server-side functions only to do "final inlining" and "image upload/resizing"